# Azure function - overriding log level of function with hyphen in name via environment variables

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

Let's say you have a function named `foo-bar` and want to mute the default azure information logs but not that function's information logs, you can do this in the host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Error",
      "Function.foo-bar": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of modifying host.json, you can also use the following in the local.settings.json and it would work

```
'AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Function': 'Error'
'AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Function.foo-bar': 'Information'
```

But dots and hyphens are not allowed in app settings. How do you get around this?

Comment: Can you please share the function code and local.settings.json which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure function - overriding log level of function with hyphen in name via environment variables

To configure logging levels for specific functions using application settings, we can't directly use dots (.) or hyphens (-) in environment variable names.

However, there's another approach to achieve,
we replace the dot (.) with an underscore (_) and keep the hyphen (-) as it is, check below:

```
"AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Function": "Error",
"AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Function_http_trigger": "Information"
```

I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack python and configured application insights.

**function code:**

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from applicationinsights import TelemetryClient

# Initialize the Application Insights telemetry client
# Make sure to replace <Your_Application_Insights_Instrumentation_Key> with your actual instrumentation key
tc = TelemetryClient("your-appinsights-instrumentationkey")

app=func.FunctionApp()
@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    # Log to Application Insights
    tc.track_trace('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        # Log error message
        logging.error("No name provided in the request.")

        return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
                status_code=200
        )
```

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Error",
      "Function_http_trigger": "Information"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Function": "Error",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Function_http_trigger": "Information"
  }
}
```

- After executing the above function getting default logs as error logs and http trigger function logs as information logs. check below:

**Output:**

[image]